# Verifying Account Transfer in Dafny

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

I'm trying to verify a simple account transfer in Dafny, and this is what I came up with:

```
function sum(items: seq<int>): int
decreases |items| {
    if items == []
    then 0
    else items[0] + sum(items[1..])
}

method transfer(accounts: array<int>, balance: int, from: int, to: int)
requires from >= 0 && from < accounts.Length;
requires to >= 0 && to < accounts.Length;
requires accounts.Length > 0;
requires sum(accounts[..]) == balance;
ensures sum(accounts[..]) == balance;
modifies accounts;
{
    accounts[from] := accounts[from] - 1;
    accounts[to] := accounts[to] + 1;
    return;
}
```

I'm just transferring one token at a time here (though actually I want to transfer an arbitrary amount).  Eitherway, it doesn't verify.  I'm wondering what else I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

The problem is that Dafny does not know anything about the `sum` function, so we have to teach it a few facts.

```
function sum(items: seq<int>): int
decreases |items| {
    if items == []
    then 0
    else items[0] + sum(items[1..])
}

lemma sum_append(xs: seq<int>, ys: seq<int>)
  ensures sum(xs + ys) == sum(xs) + sum(ys)
{
  if xs == [] {
    assert [] + ys == ys;
  } else {
    assert (xs + ys)[1..] == xs[1..] + ys;
  }
}

lemma sum_focus(xs: seq<int>, i: int)
  requires 0 <= i < |xs|
  ensures sum(xs) == sum(xs[..i]) + xs[i] + sum(xs[i+1..])
{
  calc {
    sum(xs);
    { assert xs == xs[..i] + [xs[i]] + xs[i+1..]; }
    sum(xs[..i] + [xs[i]] + xs[i+1..]);
    { forall xs, ys { sum_append(xs, ys); } }
    sum(xs[..i]) + xs[i] + sum(xs[i+1..]);
  }
}

method transfer(accounts: array<int>, balance: int, from: int, to: int)
requires from >= 0 && from < accounts.Length;
requires to >= 0 && to < accounts.Length;
requires accounts.Length > 0;
requires sum(accounts[..]) == balance;
ensures sum(accounts[..]) == balance;
modifies accounts;
{
    sum_focus(accounts[..], from);
    accounts[from] := accounts[from] - 1;
    sum_focus(accounts[..], from);

    sum_focus(accounts[..], to);
    accounts[to] := accounts[to] + 1;
    sum_focus(accounts[..], to);
}
```

The idea is that the `sum_focus` lemma allows us to break up the sum of an array into the sum of elements before `i`, plus the element at `i`, plus the sum of elements after `i`. This "focusing" step allows Dafny to reason about the assignment statements that write to the array elements `accounts[from]` and `accounts[to]`.

---

Alternative version of `sum_focus`:

```
lemma sum_focus(xs: seq<int>, i: int)
  requires 0 <= i < |xs|
  ensures sum(xs) == sum(xs[..i]) + xs[i] + sum(xs[i+1..])
{
  calc {
    sum(xs);
    { assert xs == xs[..i] + [xs[i]] + xs[i+1..]; }
    sum(xs[..i] + [xs[i]] + xs[i+1..]);
    {
      sum_append(xs[..i] + [xs[i]], xs[i+1..]);
      sum_append(xs[..i], [xs[i]]);
    }
    sum(xs[..i]) + xs[i] + sum(xs[i+1..]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks James.  Dafny actually reports "calculation between previous line and this line might not hold" for the right addition on the last line in `sum_focus`.

Comment: Weird. What about the alternative version I added to the bottom of my answer?

Comment: Yes, that works fine.  I have Boogie v2.15.2 and Z3 4.8.13.

Comment: Careful, Dafny does not yet consistently support a version earlier than z3 4.8.5

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on your suggestion I came up with this:

```
function sum(items: seq<int>): int
decreases |items| {
    if items == []
    then 0
    else items[0] + sum(items[1..])
}

lemma diff(xs: seq<int>, ys: seq<int>, acc: int, amt: int)
requires |xs| == |ys| && 0 <= acc < |xs|;
requires (forall k:int :: (0 <= k < |xs|) ==> (k == acc || xs[k] == ys[k]));
requires xs[acc] == ys[acc] + amt;
ensures sum(xs) == sum(ys) + amt;
{
    if acc == 0 {
        assert xs[1..] == ys[1..];
    } else {
        diff(xs[1..],ys[1..],acc-1,amt);
    }
}


method transfer(accounts: array<int>, balance: int, from: int, to: int)
requires from >= 0 && from < accounts.Length;
requires to >= 0 && to < accounts.Length;
requires accounts.Length > 0;
requires sum(accounts[..]) == balance;
ensures sum(accounts[..]) == balance;
modifies accounts;
{
    var 'accounts : seq<int> := accounts[..];
    accounts[from] := accounts[from] - 1;
    var ''accounts : seq<int> := accounts[..];
    diff(accounts[..],'accounts,from,-1);
    accounts[to] := accounts[to] + 1;
    diff(accounts[..],''accounts,to,1);
    return;
}
```

That seems to go through.  Its a bit clunky though --- I prefer your way.