# Lemmas in Whiley?

Tags: formal-verification

Based on an example I've [done in Dafny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398342/verifying-account-transfer-in-dafny/72399125), I was wondering how to prove similar things in Whiley?  I worked out the new syntax for properties and came up with this:

```
property sum(int[] items, int i) -> (int r):
   if i < 0 || i >= |items|:
      return 0
   else:
      return items[i] + sum(items,i+1)
```

Now, my question is: *how can I write a lemma in Whiley, like you can in Dafny?*  For example, to show that after an account transfer the total sum of all accounts is unchanged?  I can't seem to find syntax for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whiley does not currently have syntax for expressing lemmas like Dafny.  However, as a work around, we can achieve the same effect with a `function`.  Suppose I want to exploit a simple property of sums, like this:

```
// Set ith index to zero
function zeroOut(int[] xs, int i) -> (int[] ys)
requires 0 <= i && i < |xs|
// Sum decreased by appropriate amount
ensures sum(xs,0) - xs[i] == sum(ys,0):
    //
    xs[i] = 0
    //
    return xs
```

This does not verify as is.  To get this to verify requires some intervention from us (i.e. introducing a lemma).  We need to show `sum(xs,0) == xs[i] + sum(xs[i:=0],0)` where `0 <= i && i < |xs|`.   To do this ended up requiring two lemmas:

```
function lemma1(int[] xs, int[] ys, int k)
requires |xs| == |ys|
requires 0 <= k && k <= |xs|
requires all { i in k .. |xs| | xs[i] == ys[i] }
ensures sum(xs,k) == sum(ys,k):
    if k == |xs|:
        // base case
    else:
        lemma1(xs,ys,k+1)

function lemma2(int[] xs, int i, int k)
requires 0 <= k && k <= i && i < |xs|
ensures sum(xs,k) == xs[i] + sum(xs[i:=0],k):
    if i == k:
        // base case
        lemma1(xs,xs[k:=0],k+1)
    else:
        lemma2(xs,i,k+1)
```

You can see the conclusion of `lemma2` is what we are trying to show.  Notice that neither of the lemmas has a return value!  This is perhaps a slight abuse of the syntax for Whiley, but it is convenient for now until explicit `lemma` syntax is added.

Finally, we can verify our original program by exploiting the lemma as follows:

```
function zeroOut(int[] xs, int i) -> (int[] ys)
requires 0 <= i && i < |xs|
// Sum decreased by appropriate amount
ensures sum(xs,0) - xs[i] == sum(ys,0):
    //
    lemma2(xs,i,0)
    xs[i] = 0
    //
    return xs
```

That works!  However, it wasn't easy for me to figure out these lemmas would do it.  Generally, it is something of a trial-and-error process (and this would hold for tools like Dafny as well) since we don't know what the automated theorem prover can handle at any given step.